# Error when compiling libpq program in Docker: 'fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-age

I am trying to compile a C program that uses libpq library in a Docker container. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the source files into the container's working directory
COPY tmp.c .

# Compile the source file directly in the Dockerfile
RUN gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -o my_program tmp.c -lpq

CMD ["./my_program"]
```

When I try to build the Docker image using docker build . -t my_image, I get the following error:

```
tmp.c:4:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
#include "libpq-fe.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have tried installing libpq-dev package, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. What am I missing here? How can I compile my program with libpq in the Docker container?

As a next step, I also want to test for memory leaks using Valgrind. Can you please advise me on how to do this after compiling the code?
I am using Mac for the purpose of analyzing the leakage, I have used **leak** but it wasn't that much useful.

Comment: first thing: find the the absolute path (fullpath) of `pg_config`  associated with your database.

Comment: should't that be <libpq-fe.h> since it's a system library?

Comment: I might tend to go inside the interactive mode and figure out the location manullay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some **suggestions** may help:

- Add explicit including to the **PostgreSQL** headers through -**I/usr/include/postgresql** tells the compiler to look in that directory for header files.
- Skip the compiling line on the **dockerfile** and enter an **interactive bash session** and **try to do that manually** to **figure out** what is going on.
- Try to remove **-lpq** and make sure it **works without that flag**, to be aware of the source of the problem (**requires code modifications**)

I could able to have that **running** on **my machine** through adding
-**I/usr/include/postgresql** in the gcc command

```bash
RUN gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -o my_program tmp.c -lpq  -I/usr/include/postgresql
```

Comment: `-lpq` is irrelevant to this error; it's a _link-time_ flag, the problem is happening during compilation, not linking. The appropriate `-I` is what's missing and essential. (It may or may not be `/usr/include/postgresql`; depends on the particulars of this distro's libpq-dev package).

Comment: I think the only way is going manually into interactive mode and figure out the directory of the lib to be included in the -l

Comment: That or looking up the list of files in libpq-dev in Ubuntu latest via https://packages.ubuntu.com, or instructing the OP to use pkg-config to look up the arguments to use. So there are at least two options that don't involve interactive mode.

Comment: yeah except that `-I/usr/include/postgresql` just worked for me with `FROM ubuntu:20.04`

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the location of the library with

```
find / -name "libpq-fe.h"
```

Then put the full path in the include

```
#include "postgres/src/interfaces/libpq/libpq-fe.h"
```

In my case it's located in this directory ~~^

Answer (score 0):

You need to add include path for PostgreSQL in the Docker file:

```
RUN gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -o my_program tmp.c -lpq -I/usr/include/postgresql/
```

And for memory leak testing using valgrind. Use this

```
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev valgrind
CMD ["valgrind", "--leak-check=full", "./my_program"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems some files are missing in your system/docker file.

1. Update the docker file using this command: `RUN apt-get update && \ apt-get install -y libpq-dev`
2. Add the path to docker file using this command:: `RUN gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -o my_program tmp.c -lpq -I/usr/include/postgresql/`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try to reinstall the libpq-dev package.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpq-dev
```

If it doesn't work, another solution could be to use an alternative to Docker, like wsl.

Comment: Using double quotes in the include statement means the header is looked for in the same directory as the C file. Reinstalling the headers or switching to Docker won't help that at all.